# Can enum be extended in upgradeable contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3py

Can enum be extended in upgradeable contract, adding new value into the enum? If it can be extended, what are the consideration I should do before extending the enum?

Answer (score 1):

Enums are internally just integers that start counting from `1`.

As long as you are adding numbers that do not conflict with the original enum value set, the low level EVM does not care (though Solidity compiler might).

Comment: So for example, enum{a,b} i can change it to enum{a,b,c} not enum{a,c,b}, this may give conflict, correct?